# Given a specific td, get td value from the top row of same column using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Title says it all.  I have a table that is a list of dates across the top tr.  Clicking a specific td, I want to be able to get the td value from the top row of same column using Jquery.

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Jan 1</td>
     <td>Jan 2</td>
     <td>Jan 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>col 1, row 1</td>
     <td>col 2, row 1</td>
     <td>col 3, row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>col 1, row 2</td>
     <td>col 2, row 2</td>
     <td>col 3, row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>col 1, row 3</td>
     <td>col 2, row 3</td>
     <td>col 3, row 3</td>
  </tr>
```

If I click any of the td's in col 1 I want to return the value "Jan 1"

If I click any of the td's in col 2 I want to return the value "Jan 2"

If I click any of the td's in col 3 I want to return the value "Jan 3"

Make sense?

Currently, I only want this to happen for empty td's so here's the start of my jQuery.

```
$("table td:empty").dblclick(function(){

  $(TD VALUE FROM TOP OF SAME COLUMN).text();

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var index = this.cellIndex;
    console.log($('tr').first().find('td').eq(index).text());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sXhvU/).

Comment: Matt: you're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be done with the combination of `index` function and some filtering when selecting `tr`s:

```
$("table tr").not(":first").on("click", "td", function () {
    var $tr = $(this).parents("table").find("tr:first"),
        idx = $(this).index() + 1,
        srch = "td:nth-child(" + idx + ")",
        txt = $tr.find(srch).text();
});
```

Working fidle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/FgpTt/).